# Differentiating a vector function

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

For real number functions (if they are differentiable) $f$ and $d$ it holds: $$\frac{\mathbf{d}}{\mathbf{d}t}d(f(t)) = d'(f(t))f'(t).$$

Now let $t$ be a real number but $v$, $f(t)$, and $d(v)$ be vectors. The above formula may not make sense because $d$ is now a function from a vector.

Please help to "save" the formula, that is define how it can be demonstrated a similar formula for vectors.

Maybe it may be described with something like gradient?

Comment: It will be the laplacian of $d$ calculated in $f(t)$ times the gradient (matrix form) of $f$ calculated in $t$. It is the gradient of $d \circ f$

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável Can it be generalized further for infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: Have you seen the definition of derivative as a linear transformation? I don't know much about infinite dimensional spaces, but probably this definitions still holds. It will be the derivative of $d$ calculated in $f(t)$ composed by the derivative of $f$ calculated in $t$. But you won't have matrix representation.

Comment: the chain rule also holds for multivariate functions. Check [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/differentiating-vector-valued-functions/a/multivariable-chain-rule-simple-version) or [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx). In general if $f$ and $g$ are Fréchet-differentiables then $\partial(f\circ g)(x)=(\partial f\circ g)(x)\partial g(x)$ where $\partial f$ is the [Fréchet derivative of $f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável What do you mean by gradient of $f$? $f$ is a function from real variable. So it seems for me that the gradient "collapses" into a derivative (whose values are vectors not matrices)

Comment: formally, it is not the gradient per se, but the matrix such that the product of the matrix by a line vector is equal to the inner product between the gradient and the vector. This is the matrix by which you right multiply the laplacian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$, and $d: X \rightarrow Y$, where $X,Y$ are real Banach spaces.

$f$ is said to be differentiable at $t$ if there exists $f'(t) \in X$ and $E: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ such that

$$ f(t + h) = f(t) + f'(t) h + \|h\| E(h)$$

for every $h$ in some open neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb{R}$, and such that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} E(h) = 0$.

Similarly $d$ is said to be (Frechet) differentiable at $x \in X$ if there exists a bounded linear operator $d'(x): X \rightarrow Y$ and $E: X \rightarrow Y$ such that

$$ d(x + h) = d(x) + [d'(x)](h) + \|h\| E(h) $$

for every $h$ in some open neighborhood of the origin of $X$, and such that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} E(h) = 0$. Notice that the linear term $[d'(x)](h)$ is now the action of a linear operator $d'(x)$ on a vector $h$.

The **chain rule** states that if both $d,f$ are differentiable, then $d \circ f$ is differentiable and its derivative at $t$ is a linear map $(d \circ f)'(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow Y$ satisfying

$$ [(d \circ f)'(t)](h) = [d'(f(t))](f'(t) h)$$

for every $h$ in the neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb{R}$.

In the scalar case, we don't need to add the "$h$" into the chain rule because all the derivatives just multiply against $h$ as a scalar. But in the full vector case, it is important to identify how the $h$ is actually placed into the derivative equation as an input.